# abas-ERP: How to create a dataset without using the .make-command

Tags: erp, abas

I need to create a dataset in a file that is not covered by the `.make`-command. How can I achieve this?

I tried it using the file-identifier you use in the `.select`-command and the correct group-identifier (e.g. group3). When run, it prompted "wrong group".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround via `.command`

When the `invisible`-Property is set to `1`, the mask doesn't become visible and the dataset is saved immediately.

You can use it as follows:

```
.formula xtCmd = "<File-Identifier> <new>, Group-Identifier ? param1=value1|param2=value2|[invisible]=1"
.command -WAIT -ID maskID 'U|xtCmd'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use EDP or EPI.
Short example how to create a customer using EDP:

```
.type text xtedp xterr xtres xtsys
..
..: file containing the EDP commands
.file -TEMPNAME U|xtedp
..: file containing the error output of the edp command
.file -TEMPNAME U|xterr
..: file containing the id of the new customor
.file -TEMPNAME U|xtres
..
..: Create the edp command file containing two new customers
.input DATEI.F
.output new 'U|xtedp'
# hier you can write a comment for the edp file
#!database=0
#!group=1
#!action=new
#!password=yourpassword
#!charset=EKS
#!report=NUM
#!DONTCHANGE=-
#!TRANSACTION=1
# now we list all fields which we want to write
such#name#ans#plz#nort#str#
DOW#John Dow Ldt;#John Dow Ltd#12345#Someplace#Somestreet#
Max#Max Ldt;#Max Ltd#22345#Someplace2#Somestreet2#
..
..: close edp file
.output TERMINAL
..
..: Execute the edp command
.formula U|xtsys = "edpimport.sh " + " -t# -I " + 'U|xtedp' + " > " + 'U|xtrep' + " 2> " + 'U|xterr'
.system 'U|xtsys' background
..
..: G|mehr or G|success is "true" when the command could be executed successfully (on some abas-ERP versions G|success does not wort, use G|mehr)
.continue ERROR ? _G|success
.continue SHOW
!ERROR
..: Do something here!!
..
!SHOW
New customer(s) created:
.input -TEXT 'U|xtres'
.continue
```

The great benefit using edp is, that you can use transactions. If one operation fails, all transactions will be rolled back.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-). I'm glad to see someone else working with abas. Nice answer. I never thought about runing edpimport from FO